# ChartJS 'random' width

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartnew.js

im using [**chartJS**](http://www.chartjs.org/) to display a bunch of measurements. 
[image: Chart not extanding to the entire width]

It seems like the Chart itself is only using a fraction of the canvas.
I've found out that it depends on how much values I try to display. On different amounts of datapoints it extends in different ways, but more values doesn't mean it is using more space.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="1000" height="400"></canvas>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(event){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line({
        labels: ["", "", "", "", "", ""],
        datasets: [{
            data: [5, 8, 6, 1, 2, 9], // Dummy values
        }]
    }, {
        scaleOverride : true,
        scaleStartValue : 0,
        scaleSteps : 10,
        scaleStepWidth : 5,
        pointDot : false,
        scaleXGridLinesStep : 9999
    });
});
```

I've tried some fixes from the internet:

```
maintainAspectRatio: false
responsive: true
```

doesnt work for me ;(

---

**UPDATE:**

It seems like this error only occurs only when I use [ChartNew.js](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js).

I've also recreated my problem in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k311a7c1/)

Comment: If you set in your options **scaleOverride : false,** do you still have the problem ? Can you recreate your problem in a jsfiddle ?

Comment: nope it doesnt do anything different when i set **scaleOverride : false** & i've added a jsfiddle link above

Comment: Agreed.  It works OK with canvas widths below 600px or above 1080px.     It really seems to be a bug which depends on the ratio size-of-dataset / size-of-canvas. I've got no quick solution for you. I'd say report the bug in the github issue queue of the chartnew library : https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/issues